# CRest log request / response body

Tags: java, android, rest, logging, rest-client

Is there any way to print the **request** body that **CRest** (codegist) generates before sending it?

Similarly is it possible to print the **response** raw body after receiving it?

It would be very helpful for debugging.

I'm using CRest for an Android project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn on Crest logging in Android in two ways:

- execute a shell command on your connected device:

  ```
  MBP:~ roman$adb shell setprop log.tag.CodeGist VERBOSE
  ```
- set the same property programmatically using the [System.setProperty()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method

The raw response will be printed out in the logs like this:

```
03-18 07:58:52.774: VERBOSE/CodeGist(1590): org.codegist.crest.io.Response: Received Http Response
03-18 07:58:52.784: VERBOSE/CodeGist(1590): org.codegist.crest.io.Response: [{"id":14306037}]
```